# Safari iOS - cookies seem to be cleared on safari hard close

Tags: cookies, safari, mobile-safari

On my website, I store a cookie with 1 year of age. I've noticed when I do a hard close (when I slide down safari from a dock), the cookie is gone.

Is it a native Safari iOS behavior or maybe it can be with my cookie settings?

Cookie:

```
document.cookie = `approved_rules=true; expires=2023-01-03T01:11:00.000Z`;
```

Comment: The same, any ideas?